# How to use Java 8 lambdas in Jython

Tags: jython, jython-2.7

I am trying to experiment with java 8 streams and collections in jython to see if they are any efficient then when implemented in pure jython. It occurs to me it could (any comments on this also appreciated)

I started with some examples, the counting

```
from java.util.function import Function
from java.util import ArrayList
from java.util.stream import Collectors

letters = ArrayList(['a','b','a','c']);

cnt=letters.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                                            Collectors.counting()))
```

printing cnt as dictionary 
    {u'a': 2L, u'b': 1L, u'c': 1L}

so far so good. Next, I found a example on using filter on streams in java

```
List<String>strings = Arrays.asList("abc", "", "bc", "efg", "abcd","", "jkl");
//get count of empty string
int count = strings.stream().filter(string -> string.isEmpty()).count();
```

how would this translate to in jython. specifically how can one write java lambda expression like string -> sting.isEmpty() in jython?

Comment: Create a `Predicate` object and pass it to `Stream.filter`. The arrow syntax is just syntactic sugar. Behind the scenes, you're defining a `Predicate` object that has an argument and returns a `boolean` result. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-

Comment: @iceArdor thanks, used it to answer the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is an example for using a filter on a stream need a object of type Predicate (java.util.function.Predicate)

for java code:

```
List<String>strings = Arrays.asList("abc", "", "bc", "efg", "abcd","", "jkl");
//get count of empty string
int count = strings.stream().filter(string -> string.isEmpty()).count();
```

eqvivalet jython would be to first subclassing Predicate and implementing a test method.

```
from java.util.function import Predicate
from java.util.stream import Collectors

class pred(Predicate):
   def __init__(self,fn):
       self.test=fn

@pred
def mytest(s):
    from java.lang import String
    return not String(s).isEmpty() #or just use len(s.strip())==0

strings = ArrayList(["abc", "", "bc", "efg", "abcd","", "jkl"])
count = strings.stream().filter(mytest).count()
lst=strings.stream().filter(mytest).collect(Collectors.toList())
print(count)
print(lst)
```

then prints

count:

```
5L
```

lst:

```
[abc, bc, efg, abcd, jkl]
```