# Jython function to java Consumer

Tags: java, python, jython, consumer

I want to give a python function as a Consumer for a java method.

```
public Class MyObject {
    public void javaFunction(Consumer<Double> consumer){...}
}
```

and

```
def python_function(arg):
    some_code_using(arg)
```

I tried the following:

```
myObjectInstance.javaFunction(python_function)
```

and

```
myObjectInstance.javaFunction(lambda arg: python_function(arg))
```

Each time, I get *1st arg can't be coerced to java.util.function.Consumer*

I've done this before with Suppliers and it worked well. I'm using `org.python.util.PythonInterpreter`

Any ideas on how to pass such a Consumer ?

Answer (score 2):

Following hints from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44139043/6762987) by [@suvy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5580002/suvy) one could create set of helper classed like so

```
from java.util.Arrays import asList
from java.util.function import Predicate, Consumer, Function
from java.util.stream import Collectors

class jc(Consumer):
    def __init__(self, fn):
        self.accept=fn

class jf(Function):
    def __init__(self, fn):
        self.apply = fn

class jp(Predicate):
    def __init__(self, fn):
        self.test = fn
```

Which later could be used like so

```
>>> def p(x):
...     print(x)
... 
>>> asList("one", "two", "three").stream().filter(jp(lambda x: len(x)>3)).map(jf(lambda x: "a"+x)).forEach(jc(lambda x: p("foo"+x))).collect(Collectors.toList())
fooathree
```

or using built-in [`Collectors`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) class, if you need collection as result

```
>>> asList("one", "two", "three").stream().filter(jp(lambda x: len(x)>3)).map(jf(lambda x: "a"+x)).collect(Collectors.toList())
[athree]
```